# ModuleNotFoundError only occurred in conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, parlai

I usually use conda environments for my developing, but I faced strange problems in conda env. I cloned this python [repository](https://github.com/facebookresearch/ParlAI). Then, I tried to run a example, but it failed `ModuleNotFoundError` even there is exactly `parlai` directory.

```
(torch) $ which python
/Users/jef/anaconda/envs/torch/bin/python
(torch) $ python -V
Python 3.6.1 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
(torch) $ python examples/train_model.py -m drqa -t squad -bs 32 -mf /tmp/model_drqa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "examples/train_model.py", line 26, in <module>
    from parlai.core.agents import create_agent
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'parlai'
```

But if I do not use conda env, I could succeed to run the code on same directory. What is happened in my environment?

```
$ which python        
/Users/jef/anaconda/bin/python
$ python -V          
Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (x86_64)
$ python examples/train_model.py -m drqa -t squad -bs 32 -mf /tmp/model_drqa
// its working!
```

Comment: Did you install the module to make it available to your python path?

Comment: Do you mean the module is `parlai`? Do I need to do something? Without conda env, I do nothing. But it is working.

Comment: You need to go to the downloaded folder and type: `python setup.py install`. This will install parlai into your environment. I suppose this is working outside the env because you have something in your path that link to the folder you put parlai in. If this solve the issue I will create an answer.

Comment: Exactly you are right. It was just a mistake of me, not conda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your package has not been installed.

Go to the downloaded folder and type:

```
python setup.py install
```

This will install `parlai` into your environment and you can safely delete the folder.

I suppose this is working outside the env because you have something in your path that link to the folder you put `parlai` in.