# conda environment ModuleNotFoundError for yaml but it is installed

Tags: python, yaml, conda

conda ModuleNotFoundError in a virtual env but not in base

I am using Anaconda / Conda
Conda version 4.10.1
(base) Python 3.8.5

using the (base) environment, I create, build, and run my code without incident.

From the same path location and command consolte, I create and activate a conda virtual environment

I start to populate the env with the packages needed by trying to run the code and resolving each ModuleNotFoundError.
I started from Python (3.9.4)

When I get to yaml, it still fails to run on ModuleNotFoundError

python sgchecker.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sgchecker.py", line 7, in 
import yaml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'

> conda list

shows yaml (0.2.5) is installed

> pip list

does not. This is not alarming as pip list does not always show the complete list of packages.
I install via conda as preferred method.

I tried:

1. rolling back to yaml 0.1.17
2. rolling back to Python 3.8.5
3. installing yaml with pip

> pip install yaml
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement yaml
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for yaml

I tried (3) with yaml installed and removed via conda with same results

I suspect the results of (3) should lead to the solution, but so far, it has not.

related SO questions that did not help to solve the problem
[ModuleNotFoundError only occurred in conda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184325/modulenotfounderror-only-occurred-in-conda-environment)
[ModuleNotFoundError when importing package that is installed in conda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55230041/modulenotfounderror-when-importing-package-that-is-installed-in-conda-environmen)

Comment: `import sys;print(sys.path)` check your module path first

Comment: besides yaml package names pyaml

Comment: conda install pyyaml  

fixes the problem.

Comment: @merv it would have if I found it before the previous post pointed me to the same answer.

Answer (score 5):

Run this command inside conda environment:

```
conda install pyyaml
```